# Question about rsync daemon ontopic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I have a question about the security of the rsync daemon. I asked it at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53884/rsync-server-daemon-security but it hasn't got much attention. Would this be on topic here? Would it be a better fit?

Comment: Raised this in [chat] - is often a quicker way to get comment back:-) I have also flagged it over on U&L to say we're happy to take it. In saying that, it may be a bit subjective - but we can see if it gets any answers here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop thanks for the tip. I would be happy to try and make it less subjective. Lets bring it over and see what happens.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub, if you want to move the question to ITSecurity, just flag your question over there for moderator attention and tell them you want it to be moved over to ITSecurity.SE.  They can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got some fine answers there, so I'm hoping this is moot now....

If you do move it over, here are some considerations for you to take into account so you can improve your question:

I think the question could be re-focused or re-formulated in a way that would make it a better fit for this site.  The question, as you've currently posted it, is a bit narrowly focused on your particular situation, and thus less likely to be useful to others visiting the site.  I think for this site, the following sorts of questions would be more useful (i.e., more likely to be of use to other visitors):

- Is it more secure to use rsync to connect from my home device to my work device, or vice versa?
- Is it safe to use rsync without SSH?

Keep in mind one of the primary purposes of this site is to serve as a repository for high-quality answers to questions that many folks are likely to have, so to the extent that you can phrase your question in that form, the more likely it will get useful answers here.  Therefore, I encourage you to think about how to get to the core of your question, in as broadly-applicable a form as possible.

To the extent that your question is asking about how to configure some specific device (e.g., your NAS device, your Linux box) to perform some specific task, that aspect is not a good fit for this site and is probably a better fit for some other site (Unix.SE? ServerFault?).